# Multi-dimensional array indexing

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, indexing

working on an algorithm to deal 6 cards from a standard deck and compare the deals combinations to a target prime.The code bugs up due to the indexing of the Permutation array "Result".Any suggestions?

```
import random
cards=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
10,11,,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

deal=[0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range(0,6):
    deal[i]=cards.pop(random.randint(0,len(cards)-1))
    print(deal)
Result = [[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(256)] 

Result[0][0]= deal[0]+deal[1]
Result[0][1]= deal[0]-deal[1]
Result[0][2]= deal[0]*deal[1]
Result[0][3]= deal[0]/deal[1]



for i in range(2,5):
    for j in range(2^(2*j),256):
                   Result[0][j]= Result[0][j]+deal[i]
                   Result[1][j]= Result[0][j]-deal[i]
                   Result[2][j]= Result[0][j]*deal[i]
                   Result[3][j]= Result[0][j]/deal[i]
                   print(Result)
```

The error message is :
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Dealhit.py", line 16, in 
    Result[0][3]= deal[0]/deal[1]

IndexError: list index out of range. Which creats a [4x1024] array of mostly empty values.

Comment: Please post your full error message.

Comment: Do you maybe mean `len(Result) - 1`?

Comment: Yes, still getting used to the syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
for j in range(len(Result-1)):
```

Should be

```
for j in range(len(result)-1):
```

Otherwise `(result - 1)` will be exucuted before `len(result)`. Resulting in    `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`

Answer (score 0):

Because `i` is in `range(5)`, `i` can take the value 4, which, added to 2, gives 6, which is out of the bounds of `deal`.

I would recommend replacing

```
range(5)
```

by

```
range(len(deal) - 2)
```

You'll have another problem after that, when you try to assign `Result[1][j]`, because `Result` contains only one element. You need to either create a full 2d matrix of the size you need, or append items dynamically.